# AutoTrace in sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the basic difference between EXPLAIN PLAN and AUTOTRACE 
in SQL Developer. Can anybody please elaborate?

This is the query on which I am trying to get the difference inbetween Autotrace 
and Explain Plan.

```
SELECT name, address, latest_in
  FROM ( SELECT name, address, latest_in
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY address DESC) AS rowrank    
         FROM avrajit
       )
  WHERE rowrank <> 1 AND rowrank > 3;
```

Comment: please have a look at " WHERE rowrank <> 1 AND rowrank > 3;" it is confusing , you can write rowrank > 3 only.

Answer (score 5):

No better explanation than from Tom Kyte...

> the plan from autotrace is an explain plan.
>
> there is no statistic regarding hard parse and optimization - not sure
>   where you are going with that, but the optimizer estimates
>   cardinalities and those in turn with other statistics like clustering
>   factor of indexes, blocks in tables and such - are used to derive IO
>   estimations.
>
> the autotrace statistics reported however are FACTS, after executing
>   the statement, not guesses, not part of optimization.
>
> So, autotrace used explain plan to show the plan that probably, likely
>   will be used and autotrace shows the ACTUAL number of resources
>   expended to execute the query.

Full and long thread is here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=difference-of-explain-plan-autotrace-and-tkprof